# Find $f(x)$ from $f_n(x)$.

Tags: uniform-convergence

[image]

So I am learning about uniform convergence, pointwise convergence. In order to show uniform convergence, you must show $|f_n(x) - f(x)| = 0$, but I am really confused on how to find f(x) especially from the above function.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Uniform convergence is stronger than what you have said above. You have to show that $\sup_{x\in D}|f_n(x)-f(x)|<\epsilon$. (where $f:D\to\mathbb{R}$)

Comment: The point-wise limit of the $f_n$ is clearly $f(x) = e^{-x}$. If the sequence converges uniformly, it must converge uniformly to its point-wise limit. The limit can be see by looking at the coverage of the cases. For $n\to\infty$, any fixed $x$ will eventually fall within case 1.

Comment: I'm surprised no one has fully corrected you based on your misunderstanding of uniform convergence.  Here is the formal definition of what it means for a sequence of functions $f_{n}$ to converge *uniformly* to a limiting function $f$: $f_{n} \to f$ uniformly if for every $\epsilon > 0$, there is some $N \in \Bbb N$ such that if $n \geq N$, $|f_{n}(x) - f(x)| < \epsilon$.  I encourage you to check out this site to learn more about the idea of uniform convergence: http://www.mathcs.org/analysis/reals/funseq/uconv.html

Comment: Thanks! I understand it now.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For any $x \ge 0$, you have $f_n(x) = e^{-x}$ for all $n \ge x$. Thus $f_n(x) \to e^{-x}$ by definition.

You can estimate the difference between $f_n(x)$ and $e^{-x}$ in a piecewise manner:

- if $0 \le x \le n$ then $|f_n(x) - e^{-x}| = 0$
- if $n \le x \le n + e^n$ then $ 0 \le e^n + n - x \le e^n$ so that $0 \le e^{-2n}(e^n + n - x) \le e^{-n}$. It follows that $|f_n(x) - e^{-x}| \le e^{-n}.$
- If $x > n + e^n$ then $|f_n(x) - e^{-x}| = e^{-x} \le e^{-n}$.

Consequently $\sup_{x \ge 0} |f_n(x) - e^{-x}| \le e^{-n}$ so that $f_n(x) \to e^{-x}$ uniformly.